# Can the per-file geographic latency of svn merge be avoided?

Tags: svn

If I call `svn update` on a New York host, fetching from a Tokyo svn server, the number of serial round-trip communications of the operation does **not** scale linearly with the number of impacted files.

The same is not true of `svn merge`. This is a major annoyance, especially if the merge touches hundreds or thousands of files. It can mean the difference between a 5-second merge and a 15-minute merge. I personally overcome this by keeping a secondary server close by the svn server and doing merge operations on that server.

I'm wondering if I'm missing some magic svn option or upgrade that overcomes this problem.

This is with the HTTP protocol, using client v1.7.14 and server v1.6.11, although I would gladly switch protocols or upgrade versions if possible if that would overcome the problem.

Comment: Are you connecting over HTTP, file, or SVN protocol?

Comment: I'm using HTTP protocol. I've added this detail to the question.

Comment: And which version of client and server?  Both [1.7](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#httpv2) and [1.8](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#serf-skelta-default) have made updates to the HTTP communications.

Comment: Make sure that you have up-to-date Subversion client and Subversion+Apache server installation.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk My client is on 1.7.14. My server is on 1.6.11. Thank you for the links, it sounds like an upgrade might do the trick.

Comment: Upgrading to at least 1.8 on both client and server would very likely help ([they swapped out the HTTP library to something more efficient](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#neon-deleted)), but I can't back that up with anything substantive.  If you do try an upgrade and it helps, please add an answer with some details!

Comment: @PatrickQuirk Unfortunately, my IT team tells me that an upgrade of our svn environment is not possible for various reasons. But based on your links, it seems that a version upgrade is likely to do the trick. If you add an answer, I will accept it with an appropriate caveat that I wasn't able to test it.

Comment: @dshin what "various reasons" do they tell?

Comment: @bahrep not really relevant, but basically dropping support for svn and only supporting git going forward

Comment: @dshin this is ridiculous IMHO.

Comment: @bahrep Without going into great detail: at my firm, there are complex business and regulatory/legal requirements that significantly constrain how we can manage our version control repositories. In a simpler environment, the decision to drop support might be ridiculous, but in our setting it turns out to be quite understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading to at least 1.8 on both client and server would very likely help due to several improvements that were made to the HTTP layer:

1. [HTTPv2, providing fewer round-trips for better performance on high-latency networks](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#httpv2);
2. [Skelta mode, which breaks operations into a request/response per resource instead of one request/response for all resource](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#serf-skelta-default), allowing for much better proxy caching and fewer timeouts;
3. [Swapped out the HTTP implementation (neon) to something more efficient (serf)](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#neon-deleted);
4. Plus a number of other smaller improvements designed to lessen CPU load on the server (by improving cache hits) which could decrease overall response time.

However, I can't back this up with anything substantive without setting up an A/B test (which I don't have the time to do). If you (or anyone else) wants to try this and it helps, please add an answer with some details!

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't be able to test this in my particular setting, but your links convince me that an upgrade would fix my problem. Perhaps someone else with the same problem will come along at some point and confirm.